# Trying to make code that will insert arabic data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which run when I press a button in an html form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php $timestamp = date("YmdHis"); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Data Entry</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql->set_charset('utf8');
// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mortgagedb";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}


$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mortgagedb . clientstest (
reg_date TIMESTAMP,
client_code INT(6) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
project_code INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
client_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
client_id INT(14) NOT NULL,
client_id_expiry VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
client_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
client_profession VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
client_phone INT(12) NOT NULL,
income INT(6) NOT NULL,
guarantor_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
guarantor_id VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
guarantor_id_expiry VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
guarantor_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
guarantor_relation VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
unit_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
floor_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
bulding_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
project VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
governorate VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
area VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
unit_value INT(7) NOT NULL,
previous_payment INT(7) NOT NULL,
loan_maturity INT(2) NOT NULL,
mortgage_rate INT(2) NOT NULL,
annual_rate_wage INT(2) NOT NULL,
max_pay_inc INT(2) NOT NULL,
prog_max_inc INT(7) NOT NULL,
prog_min_inc INT(7) NOT NULL,
prog_max_sub INT(7) NOT NULL,
prog_min_sub INT(7) NOT NULL,
payment_graduation INT(2) NOT NULL,
iscore VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
documents VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition6 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition7 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition8 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition9 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition10 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition11 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition12 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition13 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
condition14 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attachment1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attachment2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attachment3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attachment4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attachment5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
attachment6 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table clientstest created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO mortgagedb . clientstest (client_code, project_code, client_name, client_id, client_id_expiry, client_address, client_profession, client_phone, income, guarantor_name, guarantor_id, guarantor_id_expiry, guarantor_address, guarantor_relation, unit_no, floor_no, bulding_no, location, project, city, governorate, area, unit_value, previous_payment, loan_maturity, mortgage_rate, annual_rate_wage, max_pay_inc, prog_max_inc, prog_min_inc, prog_max_sub, prog_min_sub, payment_graduation, iscore, documents, condition1, condition2, condition3, condition4, condition5, condition6, condition7, condition8, condition9, condition10, condition11, condition12, condition13, condition14, attachment1, attachment2, attachment3, attachment4, attachment5, attachment6)
VALUES ('$_POST[ccode]', '$_POST[pcode]', '$_POST[cname]', '$_POST[cid]', '$_POST[ciddate]', '$_POST[caddress]', '$_POST[cjob]', '$_POST[cphone]', '$_POST[inc]', '$_POST[gname]', '$_POST[gid]', '$_POST[giddate]', '$_POST[gaddress]', '$_POST[grel]', '$_POST[un]', '$_POST[floor]', '$_POST[bn]', '$_POST[lctn]', '$_POST[pro]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[gov]', '$_POST[area]', '$_POST[unitv]', '$_POST[pp]', '$_POST[lm]', '$_POST[mr]', '$_POST[row]', '$_POST[paytoinc]', '$_POST[maxinc]', '$_POST[mininc]', '$_POST[maxsub]', '$_POST[minsub]', '$_POST[pgr]', '$_POST[iscore]', '$_POST[docs]', '$_POST[con1]', '$_POST[con2]', '$_POST[con3]', '$_POST[con4]', '$_POST[con5]', '$_POST[con6]', '$_POST[con7]', '$_POST[con8]', '$_POST[con9]', '$_POST[con10]', '$_POST[con11]', '$_POST[con12]', '$_POST[con13]', '$_POST[con14]', '$_POST[att1]', '$_POST[att2]', '$_POST[att3]', '$_POST[att4]', '$_POST[att5]', '$_POST[att6]' )";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but I get the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_charset()
>   on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mortgage Project\db.php:21 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mortgage Project\db.php on line 21

I know the error is about `set_char`, but I'm new and don't really understand the problem here , thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to create a new table everytime you run your script? ô.o Btw. you're missing the `db_name` in your `new mysqli` For reference: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @Twinfriends I want the database to only be created if it didn't exists , as this project will be put in a server that I don't control at all

Comment: @AbdalrahmanMokhlesAslan So if you want it only then to be created, you should put it in an `IF` statement. Right now it will create a new table everytime you run the script (after the first time it will run into an error since the table exists and your query can be executed).

Comment: @Twinfriends I thought that is why I use the statement Creat IF NOT EXISTS, and so far it is working nice with me :3

Comment: @AbdalrahmanMokhlesAslan Lol sorry, I'm a blink monkey :D Totally fine

Comment: @Twinfriends cool , I'm actually glad you helped me lots :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from this line:

```
$sql->set_charset('utf8');
```

Basically its correct, but you haven't defined `$sql` at all. You need to use `set_charset` on your connection object.

So instead of your code, write:

```
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `$sql->set_charset('utf8');`. However. `$sql` is only defined on the NEXT LINE!

Try changing it to `$conn`!